# Add my own icon to <i> in HTML similar to Bootstrap's icons?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Bootstrap has a nifty way of adding an icon:

```
<i class="bi bi-arrow-right-square-fill fs-1"></i>
```

It's really nice cause I can add in the `fs-1` class to control the sizing of the icon automatically.

I have my own icon in an SVG file, and would like to do the same:

```
<i class="bi my-custom-icon fs-1"></i>
```

But I cannot figure out how to add my svg file to the element in css. I looked at the [bootstrap code](https://github.com/twbs/icons/blob/main/font/bootstrap-icons.css#L77) and they just had this:

```
.bi-arrow-right-square-fill::before { content: "\f136"; }
```

Can someone explain an example on how to load an svg file into a `<i>` HTML tag?

Comment: Copy the SVG, paste it in between `<i>` and `</i>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap is doing this via an icon font; the glyph in that font at codepoint `\f136` in that font will be the icon instead of a normal letter glyph.

Creating or modifying icon fonts can be a bit fiddly; there are some [web-based tools](https://icomoon.io) to make it a little simpler than working in a font editor, but in the long run I wouldn't recommend it. (They're a pain to maintain, since you have to regenerate and version the font every time you make a change, and cause significant problems for accessibility.)

Instead you could [convert your SVG into a data:image URI](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) and put that in your CSS, using whatever method is most convenient for your specific layout, for example

```css
.foo::before {
    content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ... </svg>')
}
```

or

```css
.foo {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ... </svg>');
  width: ..., height: ...
}
```

...or, of course, just host the SVG at a real URI and embed it using CSS as you would any other image.

Comment: What would be in the `<svg>` tag? Is there a difference between using `content` vs `background`?

Comment: @doejoe Added a link to an SVG encoder, and made the CSS examples a bit more verbose

Comment: Thanks, I tried it out and it works. But just curious why when I set `color: green` my icon is still black, whereas if I do the same for the bootstrap icon, it actually turns green color? And the `fs-1` no longer controls the sizing of the icon.

Comment: These are also artifacts of the fact that bootstrap is technically controlling a font, instead of an image; the `color` attribute affects text, not background images or embedded SVGs.  If you look at what the `.fs-1` class is doing, you'll see it sets the `font-size` attribute, so also won't work on  images, for the same reason.